# ERORR : Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. (Solution? please)

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import Timeline from '@mui/lab/Timeline';
import TimelineItem from '@mui/lab/TimelineItem';
import TimelineSeparator from '@mui/lab/TimelineSeparator';
import TimelineConnector from '@mui/lab/TimelineConnector';
import TimelineContent from '@mui/lab/TimelineContent';
import TimelineDot from '@mui/lab/TimelineDot';
import WorkIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Work';

import './Timeline.css';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

const CustomTimeline = ({title, children}) => {
    return (
      <Timeline className={'timeline'}>
      { /* Item Header */ }
      <TimelineItem className={'timeline_firstItem'}>
        <TimelineSeparator>
          <TimelineDot className={'timeline_dot_header'}>
            {WorkIcon}
          </TimelineDot>
          <TimelineConnector />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent>
          <Typography variant='h6' className={'timeline_header'}>
            {title}
          </Typography>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
      {children}
    </Timeline>
    );
};

export const CustomTimelineSeparator = () => {
  return (
    <TimelineSeparator className={'separator_padding'}>
      <TimelineDot variant={'outlined'} className={'timeline_dot'} />
      <TimelineConnector />
    </TimelineSeparator>
  );
};

export default CustomTimeline;
```

Solution please?
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `{WorkIcon}` to `<WorkIcon />`